# Return value for Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm getting stuck on something that's probably pretty simple.

I can console.log a return value from the codeAddress function, but I can't get it to return to another function that calls it. The two lines in question are called out with comments.

Please don't mind my terrible XX concatenation; I'm just trying to figure out the function calls.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
function codeAddress(zipCode) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': zipCode}, function(results, status) {
       var lat = results[0].geometry.location.d;
       var lng = results[0].geometry.location.e;
       var latlng = lat+'XX'+lng;
       return latlng;    // I can console log this value
     });
  }

var citymap = {};
function loadMap() {
  $.ajax({                                      
        url: 'getdata.php',
        data: "query=geolocate",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (zips) {
            for (var i in zips)
            {
                var entry = zips[i];
                citymap[entry['zip_code']]= {
                    scans: entry['num_scans'],
                    position: codeAddress(entry['zip_code'])  // But it will never return down here
                };
            } 
        } 
});
}
```

Comment: callbacks don't return. do your stuff in the callback itself

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For async functions, you need to provide a callback function, rather than expecting a return value.  You should be invoking the "codeAddress" function like this:

```
var entry = zips[i];
var citymapForZip = {
    scans: entry['num_scans'],
};
var zipCode = entry['zip_code'];
citymap[zipCode] = citymapForZip;
codeAddress(zipCode, getCallbackFunction(citymapForZip));
```

I've used a helper function "getCallbackFunction", which should generate the callback function for the given city map.  The callback will simply take the geocoding result, and set the citymap's "position" property.  Like this:

```
function getCallbackFunction(citymap) {
    return function(result) {
        citymap.position: result; 
    };
}
```

And finally, your `codeAddress` function should, instead of returning "latlng", pass it to the callback:

```
function codeAddress(zipCode, callback) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': zipCode}, function(results, status) {
       var lat = results[0].geometry.location.d;
       var lng = results[0].geometry.location.e;
       var latlng = lat+'XX'+lng;
       callback(latlng);
     });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with scope.

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': zipCode}, function(results, status) {
       var lat = results[0].geometry.location.d;
       var lng = results[0].geometry.location.e;
       var latlng = lat+'XX'+lng;
       return latlng;    // I can console log this value
     });
```

is returning to scope of codeAddress, but codeAddress doesn't return to caller's scope.

Answer (score 0):

Since the call to `geocode` function is asynchronous, you have to use callbacks to use its results:

```
function codeAddress(zipCode,cb) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': zipCode}, function(results, status) {
       //maybe you want to check status for error condition here
       var lat = results[0].geometry.location.d;
       var lng = results[0].geometry.location.e;
       var latlng = lat+'XX'+lng;

       cb(zipCode, latLng);
    });
}

var citymap = {};
function loadMap(cb) {
  $.ajax({                                      
        url: 'getdata.php',
        data: "query=geolocate",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (zips) {
            var i = 0,
                l = remaining = zips.length;

            for (; i <l; i++)    //better way to loop an array
            {
                var entry = zips[i];

                codeAddress(entry['zip_code'], function (zipCode,results){
                    citymap[zipCode] = {
                         scans: entry['num_scans'],
                         position: results;  
                    };

                    if (--remaining) {
                       cb();
                    } 
                });


            } 
        } 
  });
}

//call also loadMap with a callback to know when all zip are resolved
loadMap(function() {
    console.dir(citymap);    //all done!
});
```